# Where does the text in a thrown exception go?

Tags: c++, exception

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to print message from caught exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282577/how-to-print-message-from-caught-exception)

Apologies if this is basic or duplicated - I did several searches first but didn't find anything that answered this.

If I do something basic like:

```
throw exception("This thing didn't work");
```

Where can I see that?  The string doesn't show up in the output console, stack trace, or any of the .log files associated with the project.  Makes me wonder why I'm even putting a string there if it can't be seen anywhere.  I can of course use the stack trace to see where it blew up, but that kind of defeats the purpose of having exceptions in the first place.

In Java, when I give it a string, I'll see that string in the output somewhere.  I just wonder if it's possible to reproduce this behavior in C++.

Comment: I think it can be seen when the exception is caught. Other than that, probably crash dump?

Comment: You *are* catching the exception, are you?

Comment: Technically that is not valid. You are using a bug in the MS libray (std::exception does not have a constructor that takes a string). But your point is valid if you change to `std::runtime_error("This thing didn't work")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must catch the exception in order to see the string.
It can be useful to have an *exception handler of last resort* as follows:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    try {
        ...
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << "Uncaught exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

In a GUI application you can have a catch statement in the main event loop, and display the error message in a message box.

In an event-driven non-GUI application you can also have a catch statement in the main event loop, and write the error message to a log file.

These methods will make sure that you see all exceptions. Of course, most exceptions should be caught before they reach your exception handler of last resort.

Comment: This is probably it.  Problem is that some of the crashes are caused by asserts in libraries, and there seems to be no way of catching those, so even a last-resort try/catch doesn't catch everything...

Answer (score 5):

`std::exception()` has a member function called `what()`. See:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-3.3/classstd_1_1exception.html

For things like `std::logic_error`, it returns the text you passed into the constructor.